# Magento - Display SKU next to the header at the edit product page

Tags: php, magento

I need to display the products' SKU at the product edit page, at the top, just before the header containing the product name. That way the client will be able to see the product SKU without having to switch between tabs. Thank you for your time! Unfortunately the system does not allow me to post a screenshot with details so I hope this description is clear enough. [Problem solved as seen below].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this You need to Rewrite `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit` Block. You can create a Custom module for this.

In `Tech/Custom/etc/config.xml` code will be as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Tech_Custom>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Tech_Custom>
</modules>
<global>
    <blocks>
        <preview>
            <class>Tech_Custom_Block</class>
        </preview>
        <adminhtml>
           <rewrite>
               <catalog_product_grid>Tech_Custom_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Grid</catalog_product_grid>
           </rewrite>
       </adminhtml>
    </blocks>
</global>
</config>
```

In `Tech\Custom\Block\Adminhtml\Catalog\Product\Edit.php` code will be as follows:

```
class Tech_Custom_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit {

public function getHeader()
{
    $header = '';
    if ($this->getProduct()->getId()) {
        $header = $this->escapeHtml($this->getProduct()->getName()) .' - '.$this->getProduct()->getSku();
    }
    else {
        $header = Mage::helper('catalog')->__('New Product');
    }
    if ($setName = $this->getAttributeSetName()) {
        $header.= ' (' . $setName . ')';
    }
    return $header;
}
}
```

Hope this Help !!

Comment: Dear Pankaj you're a star. This did the job although I have to admit that I was not able to create the module. When I activated it the product list on the admin appeared empty without any errors. So, for now, I directly edited Edit.php and I will try later to successfully create the module. THANK you very much for your time.

Comment: Glad to hear that Solution worked for you. Please accept it as answer so that other will get benefit too.

Comment: ...I just did! Cheers...